# Bound States of a Particle in a Half-Infinite Potential Plus a Delta Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am having some conceptual problems regarding the bound states. I will try to address them using a simple problem. Consider a particle which is under the effect of a half-infinite potential plus a delta function potential.

$V(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \infty,& \text{for } x\leq0\\
    \lambda \delta(x-a),  & \text{for } x>0
\end{cases}$

Suppose that we want to find the wave function and determine the bound states. We can divide the space into 3 sections. For $x<0$ the wave function will vanish. For $0<x<a$ and $x>a$ the wave function is found by solving the free particle problem but the coefficients for these two regions must be different due to existence of the delta function potential at $x=a$. The time independent Schrodinger equation (TISE) for $0<x<a$ and $x>a$ will be:

$\psi'' = -\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi$

Using this equation, along with the boundary conditions and normalization, we should get the desired results. Intuitively, in order for the wave function to be normalizable, it must decay for $x>a$ and become zero at infinity.

$\psi(\infty)=0, \quad [BC.1]$

This corresponds to the cases in which $-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}>0$ or $E<0$. The first question as follows:

> (1) Does the fact that for $x>a$ we must have negative energy in order
> for the total wave function to be normalizable, imply anything about
> the energy in the $0<x<a$ region? More precisely, should we only
> consider $E<0$ in the region $0<x<a$ because we stated that in order
> to have a bound state we should have $E<0$ for $x>a$?

This means that the wave function in this region will be:

$\psi_R(x)=Ae^{-k(x-a)},\qquad for \quad x>a$

On the other hand, at $x=0$ the wave function must be continuous. Since for $x<0$ the wave function vanishes, we have $\psi(0)=0$. Depending on the energy of the particle being positive or negative in the region $0<x<a$ we have two possibilities for the wave function.

$\psi_L(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    Be^{-k(x-a)}+Ce^{k(x-a)},& \text{for } E<0\\
    De^{-ik(x-a)}+Fe^{ik(x-a)},  & \text{for } E>0
\end{cases}$

Continuity at $x=a$ implies that:

$\psi_L(a)=\psi_R(a),\quad [BC.2]$

Therefore we get:

$\begin{cases}
    A=B+C,& \text{for } E<0\\
    A=D+F, & \text{for } E>0
\end{cases}$

Also, at $x=0$ the wave function must be zero. Therefore:

$\psi(0)=0,\quad [BC.3]$

$\begin{cases}
    C=-Be^{2ka},& \text{for } E<0\\
    F=-De^{2ika}, & \text{for } E>0
\end{cases}$

The TISE is:

$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x) + \lambda \delta(x-a)\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$

Integrating it from $a-\epsilon$ to $a+\epsilon$ we get:

$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi'(x)|_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} +\lambda \psi(a) = 0$

where, the right hand side becomes zero if we take the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ because of the continuity of the wave function. Substituting the expressions from the general solution into this equation and taking the limit and simplifying the expressions we get:

$\begin{cases}
    k(B-C)=(\frac{2m\lambda}{\hbar^2}+k)A,& \text{for } E<0\\
    ik(D-F)=(\frac{2m\lambda}{\hbar^2}+k)A, & \text{for } E>0
\end{cases} \quad [BC.4]$

Solving the 2 sets of 3 equations we expect to find the 3 coefficients for each case. At the moment suppose that $E<0$. Using the boundary conditions I try to solve for $B$ but I get:

$kB(1+e^{2ka})=(\frac{2m\lambda}{\hbar^2}+k)(1-e^{2ka})B$

Which doesn't make sense at all! The coefficient $B$ cancels from both sides and I get nonsense! Same thing happens for $E>0$. What am I doing wrong? More precisely, the second question is:

> (2) Suppose that the particle is under the influence of the potential
> $V(x)$. What is the wave function? Do we have a bound state? If so,
> what should be the domain for $\lambda$ in order to get a bound state.
> Apparently, for $\lambda<0$ the system has a single bound state. What
> does the sign of $\lambda$ have to do with all of this? How to prove
> this? And what is the energy of this bound state?

Comment: Free particle solutions without any potential are also not normalizable. Also, the intuition here is that the solution is a standing wave: a sum of the incident and the reflected waves.

Comment: They are not bound - they extend to $+\infty$. They can be considered *quasibound*, since the part in the region $[0,a]$ is somewhat similar to the states in an infinite quantum well.

Comment: What is a quasi-bound state? Do we have a bound state or not? Can you explain your reasoning more clearly? And what is the energy of the bound (or quasi-bound) state?

Comment: Bound states are localized in a narrow region of space or at least decay rapidly away from this region. In this case the probability of finding a particle at points between $a$ and $+\infty$ is as big as for the region $[0,a]$. In some problems, e.g., when describing decay of nuclei, one would solve for region $[0,a]$, and then calculate the extension beyond thsi region as the probability of decay - but this is not introductory QM.

Comment: The cancellation of the coefficient $B$ leaves you the energy equation, from which you solve the eigen energy of the bound state. You cannot solve $B$. it is the arbitrary constant of the wave function, left for normalization.

Comment: The $\delta$ potential for one-dimension has one bound state, independent of $\lambda$.